# Why are wait, notify and notifyAll methods of the class Object?

Tags: java, oop, single-responsibility-principle

Is there are reason why these methods belong to java.lang.Object?

Since these methods are declared in java.lang.Object every class will inherited them.
That means that classes like String, ArrayList, etc. will also have them.

**Doesn't that contradict the single responsibility principle?**

> **IMPORTANT NOTICE**: I am not asking:
>
> - Why these methods are not part of Thread
> - Why every object can be locked

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think that Strings, Lists, etc. are responsible for thread locking.

Comment: They aren't. `Object` is. Those are all `final` methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The get inherited, so they are part of all classes.

Comment: I think the root question is: Why can you synchronize on any object? Since as you can synchronize on it, you probably also want to wait for it... But I don't have an answer on that (as well as I have no answer why `hashCode` is in `Object` instead of in some `Hashable` interface.

Comment: @mihi No, that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: @Boann My question is about the design not the need of these function.

Comment: IMHO the design is just broken. [And yes, I have already synchronized on a literal (interned) string and called `wait` on it. But I would not recommend it to anyone :)]. But it would be IMHO more broken if you could synchronize on everything but only wait on some objects. IMHO there should be a `Lock` or `Monitor` class to encapsulate these two concepts.

Comment: "Important Notice: I am not asking .. Why every object can be locked" It sounds like the same thing to me. The lock needs those methods. If every Object is a lock, every object needs those methods.

Comment: @Boann There are object monitors but a object is not a lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that methods are inherited does not violate the Single Responsibility Principle. It could potentially violate the SRP if those methods could be overridden. But they cannot, they are declared `final`.

[The SRP defines *reponsibility*](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf)

> In the context of the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) we define
>   a responsibility to be “a reason for change.” If you can think of more
>   than one motive for changing a class, then that class has more than
>   one responsibility.

The responsibility of managing [concurrent programming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2) with [threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2) falls on the `Object` class which owns the implementation. There is no coupling between that responsibility and any other responsibility defined in `Object` or any of its subtypes. If you ever need to change the behavior of `wait`, you'll only need to change `Object` (and possibly any call site), not `String`, not `List`, not anything else.

You might want to argue that the `Object` class itself isn't very cohesive and tries to do too much: cloning, comparing objects for equality, generating a `String` representation, etc. One could then argue back that none of those things is coupled to the other, so it's not a problem.